# C Doubly Linked List Program

Tags: c, linked-list

I have been writing a C program to work with Doubly Linked Lists. But it does not work on Dev Cpp. Can anybody point out any error? It works until the part where I add a new record and then it crashes. I'm guessing there is a problem with the scanf() function.

```
//C double-linked list program

struct stu {

int roll,ph,ch,ma;
stu *plink,*nlink;
};

void addstu(stu *p,stu *n) { //add

stu *s;
int roll,ph,ch,ma;

printf("HELLO STUDENT!\nYour roll no.? ");
scanf("%d",&roll);

printf("\nPhysics score? ");
scanf("%d",&ph);

printf("\nChemistry? ");
scanf("%d",&ch);

printf("\nMath? ");
scanf("%d",&ma);

s->roll=roll;
s->ph=ph;
s->ch=ch;
s->ma=ma;

s->plink=p;
s->nlink=n;
}

void remstu(stu *s) { //remove

stu *next;
next->plink=s->nlink;
free(s);
}

// Main function
int main() {

stu *s;
int choice=0, ct=0;

while(choice!=4) {

printf("\n\t\tWELCOME TO RECORDS\n\n1. ADD\n2. REMOVE\n3. SEE\n4. EXIT\nEnter your choice(1-4): ");
scanf("%d",&choice);

switch(choice) {

    case 1:
        stu *t;
        addstu(s,t);
        s=t;
        free(t);
        ++ct;
        break;

    case 2:
        remstu(s);
        break;

    case 3:
        for(int i=0;i<ct;++i) {
            printf("\n\nRoll no. %d\nPhysics %d\nChemistry %d\nMath %d",s->roll,s->ch,s->ph,s->ma);
            s=s->plink;
        }
        break;

    case 4:
        exit(0);
        break;

    default:
        printf("Please enter correct choice(1-4)!");
}
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a runtime error. No build error.

Comment: If you get crashes, then you should run the program in a debugger to locate the crash. You should also build with more warnings enabled, add at least the `-Wall` flag, maybe even `-Wextra` and `-pedantic` too. Warnings are just as important to fix as errors, because warnings often point out *undefined behavior* or other similar problems in your code. And yes, GCC is able to catch the problem you have and warn about it.

Answer (score 3):

```
s->roll=roll;
```

The pointer `s` in function `addstu()` is never initialized and dereferencing it leads to undefined behavior hence the crash.

Do

```
s = malloc(sizeof(struct stu)); /* Allocate memory */
```

I hope you have

```
typedef struct stu stu;
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading your code, you have a *lot* of undefined behaviors going on.

Lets take `case 1` as example:

```
stu *t;
addstu(s,t);
s=t;
free(t);
++ct;
```

The first problem is that when you call `addstu` the variable `s` is not initialized. Uninitialized (non-static) local variables have an *indeterminate value*, and will in practice seem to be random. The same goes for the variable `t`. So when in `addstu` you will set the nodes links to uninitialized pointers.

You call `addstu` which should create a new node, and add to the list. But what happens to that node you should create? Nothing, it's not passed on from the `addstu` function, the function doesn't even link it into the list properly (disregarding the uninitialized variables for a moment) so no new nodes will be added.

You then assign `t` to `s`, thereby initializing `s` but *with an indeterminate value* so nothing really changes.

You then continue to call free the memory for `t` (even though you haven't allocated any memory), and as `s == t` at that moment, that's the same as freeing `s`. Assignment of pointer only copies the pointer and not the memory that it points to.

There are probably many other problems with the code, but I only got that far. I suggest you start over, and with something simpler to learn how pointers and dynamic memory allocations work. Then come back to this problem, but before you write any code, try to draw the operations on paper. For example, what should an empty list look like? How would it look after adding the first node? After the second and third node? How would it look if you add a node to the end of the list? To the beginning of the list? Once you got all that clear, you can start writing your code.